# IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern Type 6.1 deployment error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server

I get the following error when I deploy an instance of a pattern created using the "Out of the Box" IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern Type 6.1 Template on IBM PureApplication System. The template uses the artifacts/WorklightStarter.ear file as the enterprise application for the WL Server part.

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console
>   initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   FWLSE0206E: The project /WorklightStarter failed to initialize,
>   because the project database schema for data source
>   jdbc:db2://10.14.15.184:50000/WLRTIME is from version N/A, which is
>   not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131123-2150. Use
>   the Worklight ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema.
>   [project WorklightStarter].

I have seen posts that explain the WL Runtime DB migration I need go through to fix this error. But that migration should be required for WL Applications that were built on an earlier version of WL (for e.g 5.0.6). I am getting this error from an Out of the Box WorkliteStarter.ear application that is shipped with the IBM Mobile Application Platform Pattern Type 6.1 Template. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error you saw is usually caused by not upgrading the database workload standard to match the version of your worklight pattern.

Can you please check following things?

a) Have you installed the database workload standard shipped with 6.1?

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/pureapp/t_pureapp_installing_DB_workload_standards.html

b) Did you explicitly re-selected the workload standard in virtual application builder after importing the sample pattern? There is an issue with DB2 component that database workload standard is not selected correctly when importing the pattern zip. So to workaround this, you need to make sure the imported pattern has selected correct database workload standard

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/pureapp/t_pureapp_importing_sample_wl_application_pattern.html

Comment: I checked and I did not have the WL 6.1 Runtime and Reports DBs shipped with the pattern package in the system. I have created 2 new database workload standards using the DB zips provided in the pattern package, one for WL Runtime and one for Reports and pointed my WL pattern to use the new WL 6.1 level database workload standards I created and redeployed the pattern. I do not get this error anymore. Thanks for guiding me here with the correct fix.